Send custom message to Kafka topic
The task is to send message with concrete value to Kafka topic.
For example, I want to send "someValue" as plain text.
What Kafka property in PublishKafkaRecord_2_6 should I use for this purporse?
I see, for example, "FreeFormTextRecordSetWriter" as a service, which writes the contents of a RecordSet as free-form text.
But where inside PublishKafkaRecord_2_6 I can set my "someValue" to publish it in target topic.


where inside PublishKafkaRecord_2_6 I can set my "someValue"

You wouldn't. The Kafka processor just sets up the producer for Kafka client details and serialization.
You'd setup an incoming processor, such as using GenerateFlowFile

So, GenerateFlowFile I should connect with PublishKafkaRecord, write simple text-content  in "Custom Text"-fileld  and in PublishKafkaRecord i use FreeFormTextRecordSetWriter to write this content to topic ?

That sounds correct to me
